# AddThis Facebook Send Button Not Displaying

Tags: asp.net, facebook, addthis

I'm using asp.net and cannot get the AddThis Facebook "Send" button work. They claim (http://www.addthis.com/help/custom-buttons#facebook-send) this is the code needed:

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_send"></a>
</div>
```

But it doesn't display anything at all. I already have an AddThis toolbar implemented and everything else works fine, even the Facebook "Like" button, which uses the following code:

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like"></a>
</div>
```

Since I can't really find any posts about this problem, and since AddThis says it should work, could the problem be because of the .net framework?

Comment: ASP.NET has nothing to do with AddThis, AddThis is plain HTML and Javacript, nothing else. Though they say it "should" work, does not mean that it does, you could have something in your scripts blocking it for example. Did you ask in their own Forum yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem. This is how I resolved it:

1) Moved the AddThis javascript src tag to the bottom of the page where I'm loading the buttons

2) Added the below to the HTML tag of my page.

> xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"

I got this from AddThis Send button page

**Edit:**
It looks like the AddThis Facebook button has changed quite a bit, [here is the new page for it](http://www.addthis.com/social-plugins/facebook-send-button#.UKEK3uOe9g8), since the other link goes to a 404.